# Product of Unit Ball and Real Line Is Hoemomorphic to Vector Space

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $B$ be the boundary of its unit ball.  Let $d_X$ be the metric induced by the norm on $X$ restricted to $B$.  Then, is the topology on $X\cong B\times \mathbb{R}$ with product metric
$
d_X \times \|\cdot - \cdot\|?
$

I was thinking, and I guess that the map
$$
x \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
(\frac{x}{\|x\|},\|x\|) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
should define a homeomorphism from $X$ to $B\times \mathbb{R}$.  However, beyond this point I'm confused since the latter looks like a cylender in my mind..but maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map is not even continuous. If $x_n \to 0$ in $X$ then $\frac {x_n} {\|x_n\|}$ need not even have a limit.

But your map is  a homeomorphism from $X\setminus \{0\}$ onto $B \times (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, it s. And it is instructive to see how the two sets look like when $X$ is the real line. @Zorn'sLama

Comment: Though, I'm wondering shouldn't the co-domain be $B\times (\mathbb{R}-\{0\})$?

Comment: @Zorn'sLama Yes, you are right.

Comment: Great, then your answer really helped me understand!  Thank you.

Comment: @Ennar You are right.